# Footer CSS isn't being applied

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, footer

When I write this, the word Hello appears in the top of my page instead of the bottom:

```
<footer> Hello </footer>
```

Here is the important part of my CSS file:

```
.footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    height:100px;
    background: black;
}
```

I really don't know what's wrong. 
I'm working under **Ruby on Rails**, and I'm using **Pdfkit** to transform my html page into pdf, but I don't think this matters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/XtWRv/1/)**

footer is tag in your html not a class so

```
footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In CSS replace `.footer` with `footer` and it will work and the working fiddle is here

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/568Ad/)

And just for your clarification.

In html we create tags and some of them have attributes like `class` and `id`. And below shows how you can assign CSS.

if `class` is attribute then you use the `.`

```
<div class="new"/>
CSS would be 
.new{}
```

if attribute is `id` then you use `#`

```
<div id="new"/>
CSS would be
#new{}
```

if css is directly on tag with no attriutes, directly use the tag. (This is where you were getting stuck)

```
<div/>
CSS would be
div{}
```

happy coding!!!!