# How can I fix my footer's CSS properties not displaying correctly?

Tags: html, css

My footer doesn't show CSS properties properly.

I tried to change the height, weight, padding, overflow but nothing changed.
The code is down below

```css
.footer {
  background-color: black;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleody.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
    in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
    of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes
    from a line in section 1.10.32.
  </p>
</body>

<footer>
  <div class="footer-content">
    <p>Επικοινωνήστε μαζί μας</p>
  </div>
</footer>

</html>
```

Comment: Your footer is outside the body element. This is invalid HTML.

Comment: You're targeting the footer with a class selector which doesn't match any class. You need to use an _element type_ selector or target a class which exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Footer CSS isn't being applied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25077187/1264804)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using a CSS selector that would not select anything in the HTML document. You may have meant to use `footer`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CSS Template</title>
<style>
footer{
    background-color:black;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:40px;
    color:#fff;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styleody.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>


<body>
<p>
Where does it come from?

Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.


</p></body>
<footer>
<div class="footer-content">
<p>Επικοινωνήστε μαζί μας</p>
</div>
</footer>
</html>
```

Or `.footer-content`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>CSS Template</title>
<style>
.footer-content{
    background-color:black;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:40px;
    color:#fff;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styleody.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>


<body>
<p>
Where does it come from?

Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.


</p></body>
<footer>
<div class="footer-content">
<p>Επικοινωνήστε μαζί μας</p>
</div>
</footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because there is no class name .footer in your code

and you have to put the `footer` inside the `body` not outside

```
.footer-content {
  background-color: black;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  float: left;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleody.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
    in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33
    of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes
    from a line in section 1.10.32.
  </p>

<footer>
  <div class="footer-content">
    <p>Επικοινωνήστε μαζί μας</p>
  </div>
</footer>

</body>


</html>
```